# Automating wildcard subdomain for users GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, wildcard-subdomain, google-app-engine-php

I have an app engine instance project under let's say: `cloud.domain.com`

My goal is to be able to give a user of my a unique url that they can then map to their own domain using a CNAME record. Basically how you would connect to a [domain to a squarespace account](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205812378-Connecting-a-domain-to-your-Squarespace-site#toc-step-5---add-the-first-cname-record).

It could really be anything like so:

```
userid.cloud.domain.com
userid.domain.com
```

Is this even possible with GAE? I've researched [wildcard mappings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#wildcard_mappings) but there really isn't any solid advice on the topic.

Is this even possible or should I look elsewhere to accomplish this kind of task?

Answer (score 4):

1. You need a domain host that allows you to set up wildcards in the DNS records
2. Create a CNAME for *.mydomain.com (or *.sub.mydomain.com) pointing to ghs.googlehosted.com
3. In App Engine section in Cloud Console, under settings/custom domains, add the custom domain (you will need to verify ownership by adding a TXT record)
4. Once verified, add *.mydomain.com (or *.sub.mydomain.com) to the point section
5. Webapp2 in Python has a function DomainRoute to wire this up at the code level, you will need the find the PHP equivalent

Comment: I'm struggling to add *.mydomain.com into the box - please see attached screenshot. Was this the same field you were using, Ron? https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pae08ohx3tr7ac/Screenshot%202016-05-26%2015.21.26.png?dl=0